# TypeError : Unhashable type

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of list of tuples : something like `[ [(1,0),(2,0),(3,0)],[(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)....]]`
I used this statement

```
set([(a,b)for a in range(3)]for b in range(3))
```

But it gives me an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

I have 2 questions  for the Python Guru's:

a) When I look at the Python definition of Hashable -

> "An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes during its lifetime (it needs a **hash**() method)"

when I used  dir function on the expression above

```
dir([(a,b)for a in range(3)]for b in range(3))
```

it seems to say the `__hash__` is there. So, why do I get the error?

I was able to get `[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]`
by using the list command :

```
list(list((a,b) for a in range(3)) for bin range(3))
```

b)list and set both takes Iterable as parameter. How come one works(list) and another doesn't (set)?

Answer (score 39):

You are creating a `set` via the `set(...)` call, and `set` needs hashable items. You can't have set of lists. Because lists aren't hashable.

`[[(a,b) for a in range(3)] for b in range(3)]` is a list. It's not a hashable type. The `__hash__` you saw in `dir(...)` isn't a method, it's just None``.

A list comprehension returns a list, you don't need to explicitly use list there, just use:

```
>>> [[(a,b) for a in range(3)] for b in range(3)]
[[(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)], [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)], [(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]]
```

Try those:

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3}
>>> b= [1, 2, 3]
>>> type(a)
<class 'set'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'list'>
>>> {1, 2, []}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> print([].__hash__)
None
>>> [[],[],[]] #list of lists
[[], [], []]
>>> {[], [], []} #set of lists
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: So what types are unhashable?

Answer (score 23):

## TLDR:

### - You can't hash a list, a set, nor a dict to put that into sets

### - You can hash a tuple to put it into a set.

Example:

```
>>> {1, 2, [3, 4]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

>>> {1, 2, (3, 4)}
set([1, 2, (3, 4)])
```

Note that hashing is somehow recursive and the above holds true for nested items:

```
>>> {1, 2, 3, (4, [2, 3])}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Dict keys also are hashable, so the above holds for dict keys too.

Comment: I'm working with lists of lists, so this is actually very useful. Thanks.

Comment: creating a tuple representation of a list is faster than a string representation via e.g. `repr( [1,2,3] )`, right? What about nested lists?

Comment: @AlexandrNil for nested lists you could use comprehensions, i.e., for a 2-dimensional list 
`a = [[1,2],[3,4]]  # a 2 by 2 matrix` can be transformed via `a = set(tuple(tuple(x) for x in a)))`

Answer (score 14):

A list is unhashable because its contents can change over its lifetime. You can update an item contained in the list at any time.

A list doesn't use a hash for indexing, so it isn't restricted to hashable items.

Answer (score 9):

The **real** reason because `set` does not work is the fact, that it uses the hash function to distinguish  different values. This means that sets only allows hashable objects. Why a list is not hashable is already pointed out.

Answer (score 7):

... and so you should do something like this:

```
set(tuple ((a,b) for a in range(3)) for b in range(3))
```

... and if needed convert back to list

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that instances of `list` do not provide a `__hash__` --rather, that attribute of each list is actually `None` (try `print [].__hash__`). Thus, `list` is unhashable.

The reason your code works with `list` and not `set` is because `set` constructs a single set of items without duplicates, whereas a list can contain arbitrary data.