# Python Error: Unhashable Type List

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to do the following in python:

1. Splitting a file of para of statements into sentences.
2. Splitting these sentences with contractions into words.
3. Trying to remove stopwords from the set of words.

When I do the 2nd step I get the result [['Hello','World'], and so on.
I understand ( if I am not wrong) I have got a list or a nested list so the probable error. But have got no idea to solve the error.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
file = open('C:/temp1/1.txt','r')
text = file.read() # read the contents of the text file into a variable
result1 = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)#split para into sentences
print "Split sentences are " 
print result1
tokenizer=WhitespaceTokenizer()
result2 = [tokenizer.tokenize(sent) for sent in result1]#obtains the splitted sentences with contractions
print "Split words in each sentences are "
print result2
english_stops=set(stopwords.words('english'))
result3=[word for word in result2 if word not in english_stops]
print result3
Error:
Split sentences are 
['Hello World.', "It's good to see you.", 'Thanks for buying this book.', "Can't is a contraction."]
Split words in each sentences are 
[['Hello', 'World.'], ["It's", 'good', 'to', 'see', 'yTraceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Learn NLTK\import nltk.py", line 34, in <module>
result3=[word for word in result2 if word not in english_stops]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
ou.'], ['Thanks', 'for', 'buying', 'this', 'book.'], ["Can't", 'is', 'a',   'contraction.']]
```

Do I need to use a nested for loop so as to obtain the stopwords filtering?
I have checked the related questions which had the same error but I am new to python so I am unable to grasp any idea from those related questions.
Any help would be appreciable.
Arc.

Comment: It looks like you have a list of lists so the test in your last list comprehension is not possible, you need to iterate over each nested list and each word in each list

Comment: Do you have a document which could show an example of iterating over each nested list and each word in each list?

Comment: Actually can you just test if `set(stopwords.words('english'))` works, I think this may be the error

Comment: @EdChum:No the above code works fine

Comment: I have solved the problem using nested for loops and the solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check if a list is in your set. Lists are unhashable, hence your error.
I'm no expert on list comprehensions, and other people will be able to answer your questions better, but given your example, I would try the following:

```
for tokens in result2:
    for word in tokens:
        if not word in english_stops:
            result3.append(word)
```

(so the answer is; yes, you need to loop through your nested list)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a set of lists since lists are not hashable. There are several answers here. you can check this one out [TypeError : Unhashable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754102/typeerror-unhashable-type)