# Unhashable type 'list' - Wordcount

Tags: python, regex, nltk, word-count, gensim

```
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader("path",'.*',encoding="latin1")
docs = [corpus.words(f)for f in corpus.fileids()]
docs2 = [[w.lower()for w in doc]for doc in docs]
docs3 = [[w for w in doc if re.search('^[a-z]+$', w)]for doc in docs2]
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_list = stopwords.words('english')

docs4 = [[w for w in doc if w not in stop_list]for doc in docs3]
```

I have written the following code , which reads a corpus of files. FOllowed by that i have done some preprocessing steps ir removing punctuations , stopwords etc. I would now like to perform a word count and find most frequent words used in the text. I used the following code below to do so so.
for word in docs4:

```
if word in word_counter:
    word_counter[word] += 1
else:
    word_counter[word] = 1

popular_words = sorted(word_counter, key = word_counter.get, reverse = True)
```

However i get the following error. --

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rohanhm.2014/PycharmProjects/untitled1/bp.py", line 18, in <module>
    if word in word_counter:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using `list` as your keys in `word_counter` dictionary?

Comment: Maybe this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754102/typeerror-unhashable-type

Answer (score 0):

I think 'word' is list type.
Maybe you make a mistake by using a list contains only one string inside, but you think it is a string type.

Answer (score 0):

Because thew word_counter is a multi list, it's unhashable.You can write this

```
   from itertools import chain
   print list(chain(*l))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient way to determine the popular words of a text in nltk.

```py
>>> import nltk
>>> words = ['a','b','a','a','b','c','d']
>>> fd = nltk.FreqDist(words)
>>> fd.most_common(3)
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks @char bugs. I am aware of this method. However it does not work when words = [['a','b','b'], ['a','a','c'], ['d','a','d']]. Any ideas for such a list?

Comment: Several ideas! a) `word = corpus.words()` to store all words of the corpus in one list. b) `words = [w for doc in docs for w in doc]` to merge your word lists to a single one. c) `fd_list = [nltk.FreqDist(doc) for doc in docs]` to get a list that contains a FreqDist for each document.

Comment: Used this to find individual wordcount of each file.
for i in range (len(fids)) :
    print ("Top Words" + str (i+1) + ":")
    print (fd_dist[i])
    print ("") and wordscount = [w for doc in docs4 for w in doc] to find total word count. Thank you.