# Collecting Unique tweets REST API

Tags: python, rest, twitter

**Background:** I want to get only unique tweets. According to comments on stackoverflow, one way to do this is to create a  set

However, when I try the following code, I get an TypeError: Unhashable. I found some info here [TypeError : Unhashable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754102/typeerror-unhashable-type). I also know I can remove duplicates in MongoDB, where I am storing, but it's cleaner if I do it before storing.

**Question**: Is there a way I can only collect unique tweets?

```
results = []
pages = 2 
counts = 100

while True:        
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = keywords, since="2017-07-21", until="2017-07-27", count = counts, lang = language,monitor_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit=True).pages(pages):
        results.extend(tweet)


    results = set(results)
```

Comment: It is difficult to say without a compete example, but you are trying to hash a list, which is not allowed. You should instead try to put every member of the list in the set `a = set() for tweet in results: a.add(tweet)`

Comment: I tried the code `a = set() for tweet in results: a.add(tweet)` but i get an error: invalid syntax

Comment: if you pasted the line in directly you would have got a syntax error for sure, did you try it on separate lines with the correct indentation? 

Also: Please provide errors you encounter while debugging to help us better solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to say for sure without a concrete example

```
{ ~ }  » python                                                                                                                            
>>> results = ["hi", "hello", "hi", "goodbye"]
>>> a = set()
>>> for tweet in results:
...     a.add(tweet)
...
>>> print a
set(['hi', 'hello', 'goodbye'])
>>>
```

as you can see above the set has only 1 "hi", you shouldn't try to hash the entire list as a whole.

Ok, as per your comments I did a littler reverse engineering, I determined that the tweets have a text field that you need to add to the set,

so just replace `a.add(tweet)` with `a.add(tweet.text)`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried the code per your example with the proper syntax and indentations. However, I get still get the following error using the `tweepy.Cursor` code I provided above. `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Status'`