# How to fix TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, dictionary, compression

**Decompression Function: load a file bin from compression function **

```
def lzwDecompressionText () :
loadCompressed = open ("CompreText.bin","rb")
compressed = pickle.load(loadCompressed)    
print("", compressed)
dictionary =defaultdict(dict)
lenDictionary = 256
decompressed_data = ""
string=""
for i in range(256):
    dictionary[i] = chr(i)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/anton/Documents/GitHub/Project-LZW/LZW-Project/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    lzwDecompressionText()
  File "c:\Users\anton\Documents\GitHub\Project-LZW\LZW-Project\textLzw.py", line 70, in lzwDecompressionText
    if not (code in dictionary):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

```
for code in compressed:
    if not (code in dictionary):
        dictionary[code] = string + (string[0])
decompressed_data += dictionary[code]
if not(len(string) == 0):
    dictionary[lenDictionary] = string + (dictionary[code][0])
    lenDictionary += 1
string = dictionary[code]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at least some of your `code` values in `compressed` (loaded from a pickled file) simply happen to be of type `dict`, contrary to your expectation of `int`.

See also: [TypeError : Unhashable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754102/typeerror-unhashable-type/34520762).

Comment: the problem is in the compression function, or the problem is pickle?

Comment: The problem is most likely in your data that you unpickle. Could you show us the output of that `print("", compressed)` line?